# Dell OMCI returns no data in Powershell when querying DCIM_View

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use Dell's OMCI system to retrieve information about the server. The problem I am having is I cannot get any of the DCIM_View* classes to work. It does not throw any errors, just a blank line. Below is a sample of the script. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName COMPNAMEHERE -Namespace root/dcim/sysman -Class DCIM_VirtualDiskView
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, OMCI supports only Intel Controllers, you cannot get instances on these DCIM_View class if its not Intel Setup.

If still DCIM_VirtualDiskView is none, then make sure the system has a VD created on it.